# Send Admin Emails to Multiple Email Addresses

Tags: admin, email

Is there a hook that would allow me to email multiple email addresses for the default admin email notifications?

I was hoping I could build an array:

```
$adminEmails = array('me1@example.com', 'me2@example.com');
```

Then have all admin emails (like new user notifications) sent to $adminEmails

Possible?

Comment: There's a discussion here - doesn't look like there's a solution: [https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10726](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10726)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
update_option( 'admin_email', 'me1@example.com, me2@example.com' );
```

Note that the value is a string; open and close quotes only!

Comment: Thanks @shanebp - but it doesn't work. It just merges them into a single string in the options, so it tries sending to: me1@example.comme2@example.com

Comment: That's too bad... So, for just admin emails re new users, the function is pluggable. So you could create a version that sends to multiple hardcoded emails re admins. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_user_notification

Comment: Thanks shanebp - I think what you suggest is actually the best solution for my needs.

Comment: @PatGilmour Then please mark it as solution.

Comment: @PatGilmour Well if the original answer is incorrect it probably shouldn't be marked as correct. I would either mark sMyles's answer correct or update shanebp's answer with the solution offered in the comments.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done by filtering the `wp_mail` function, checking if `to` is set to the admin email, and if so, add your additional emails addresses, and return args back to `wp_mail`

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'my_custom_to_admin_emails' );

/**
 * Filter WP_Mail Function to Add Multiple Admin Emails
 *
 *
 *
 * @param array $args A compacted array of wp_mail() arguments, including the "to" email,
 *                    subject, message, headers, and attachments values.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function my_custom_to_admin_emails( $args ) {
    // If to isn't set (who knows why it wouldn't) return args
    if( ! isset($args['to']) || empty($args['to']) ) return $args;

    // If TO is an array of emails, means it's probably not an admin email
    if( is_array( $args['to'] ) ) return $args;

    $admin_email = get_option( 'admin_email' );

    // Check if admin email found in string, as TO could be formatted like 'Administrator <admin@domain.com>',
    // and if we specifically check if it's just the email, we may miss some admin emails.
    if( strpos( $args['to'], $admin_email ) !== FALSE ){
        // Set the TO array key equal to the existing admin email, plus any additional emails
        //
        // All email addresses supplied to wp_mail() as the $to parameter must comply with RFC 2822. Some valid examples:
        // user@example.com
        // User <user@example.com>
        $args['to'] = array( $args['to'], 'another@domain.com', 'Admin4 <admin4@domain.com>' );
    }

    return $args;
}
```

We return the TO as an array, as `wp_mail` will handle the array and explode it as needed to send the email

Comment: One thing to be careful of, say you request password reset and your email is the same as the `admin_email` option, those other emails will get that email as well ... just keep that in mind, it only checks the TO when emails are sent, doesn't check if it's supposed to be an admin email (as I dunno how to even do that right now)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, it uses the update_option_* filter, I believe it to be the right way to go here.
add this to a plugin or your theme functions.php file, 
and then you can safely put comma separated admin emails in the settings->general screen.

```
add_filter('pre_update_option_admin_email','sanitize_multiple_emails',10,2);

function sanitize_multiple_emails($value,$oldValue)
{
    //if anything is fishy, just trust wp to keep on as it would.
    if(!isset($_POST["admin_email"]))
        return $value;

    $result = "";
    $emails = explode(",",$_POST["admin_email"]);
    foreach($emails as $email)
    {
        $email = trim($email);
        $email = sanitize_email( $email );

        //again, something wrong? let wp keep at it.
        if(!is_email($email))
            return $value;
        $result .= $email.",";

    }

    if(strlen($result == ""))
        return $value;
    $result = substr($result,0,-1);

    return $result;
}
```